# If Apocryphal Texts Never Were Apocryphal, How Would This Affect Christianity?

Tags: culture, alternate-history, religion

*The Christianity Stack Exchange has made it absolutely clear that this* **IS** *a worldbuilding question.*

If modern theology were any consideration, the official stories in the Old and New testaments made up only the bare bones of the entire Bible. In recent decades, archaeologists have dug up many, many apocryphal, or hidden, stories that, if ever canonized, would completely change the cultural attitude and evolutionary history of Christianity.

These apocryphal texts include the following:

- *Life of Adam and Eve*, a text describing the story of Adam and Eve in far greater detail, leading up to their expulsion from paradise right down to their deaths
- *The Book of Enoch*, which described the Watchers, angels who fell to Earth to teach humanity hidden knowledge, even interbred with them, the resulting children being the Nephilim--**giants**
- *Joseph and Aseneth*, a more detailed description of the relationship between the original owner of the Coat of Many Colors and the daughter of an Egyptian priest
- *Yahweh and Asherah*, the idea that the Divine Male is accompanied by a Divine Female
- *The Gospel of Philip* and *The Gospel According to Mary Magdalene*, both of which picture Mary Magdalene not just as a reformed prostitute but as a major Disciple

In an alternate history, none of the listed texts are apocryphal and instead can be found in the official canon. What kinds of differences should I expect to see in the cultural attitudes and evolutionary history of Christianity?

Comment: Is there a way to read the texts so we can get a better idea of what would change and how?

Comment: I'm going to say this is probably too broad. Christianity has been around for thousands of years, and many of these texts even predate that. Even choosing to focus on one of them is probably going to have effects larger than we can reliably estimate.

Comment: Christianity SE does not decide what is on topic for World Building.  That said alternate history is on-topic in and of itself.  This question though is very very very broad.

Comment: A good narrowed topic might be:  *What would the impacts of this be on the church's attitude toward women?*  As an example.

Comment: Is the question asking what if they were canonical (widely accepted by the church) or historical (events that happened)?  Currently they are believed to be neither, at least by most historians and church leaders.

Comment: If you read the Bible, it doesn't *actually* state that Mary (from) Magdalene was a prostitute...  It mention a prostitute in *one* verse - then Mary in the *next* verse.  However, an unwed/widowed woman travelling from place to place with a group of men, were highly frowned upon; so the Church eventually chose to "merge" the two *unrelated* verses into **"Mary was a prostitute"**... possibly to undermine things like the Magdalena-gospel.

Comment: The linked question (that this is closed as a duplicate of) has reopen votes.  This current question has an answer.  If the other question gets reopened, somebody please flag to let us know; it'd probably then be better to reopen *this* question and delete the other, instead of having an open question there and an answered closed question here.  (That said, I agree with the folks saying this is too broad as written.)

Comment: @JohnWDailey At least some of the texts that you mention are not new discoveries and were widely known in the past. The book of Enoch, for example, was known at the time of that the conventional canon-list was chosen, and it was rejected from the list by most denominations. It is not a new discovery at all; it just keeps falling out of the awareness of the common folk and has been so-called "rediscovered" several times throughout history. When "discovered" some people say "What do you mean you discovered it? Here is an essay about it written 100 years ago."

Comment: My previous comment is essentially pointing out that this question is partially based on a false premise. Also note that the Catholic church, historically the dominant denomination of Christianity, accepts some of the apocryphal texts, so you can actually see the answer to your question by looking at real history.

Comment: @Aaron  The official Book of Enoch mentioned Enoch in only one sentence.  The aprocryphal Book is a more appropriate definition.

Comment: @JohnWDailey I am not sure what your point is with that comment. Your comment does support my other comment I made in response to the answer below, was your meant in response to that? That is, where I mentioned the fact that the book of Enoch was modified? "Modified" is an understatement, but there is not enough room here for a full discussion. It is believed that the book of Enoch is actually a collection of works mashed together, and that only a small part of it might be from the prophet Enoch. Anyway, I was just trying to give you some more information; hopefully it is useful.

Comment: While this is no longer a duplicate (as the other question has been deleted), it is still overly broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I can give you a straight out answer, but I hope this will point you in the right direction.

I would start by considering why these works were cast out of the canon in the first place. Things to consider (though very point of view based)?

The effect this would have on the views of 'hot button topics', such as:

- Slavery
- Views on women (not just a woman, but an 'ex prostitute' as a disciple?)
- Interaction with 'non believers'? Would this diverge from 'kill, convert, or subjugate'?

It could set forward women's rights a few hundred years (so women might be treated equally as of the 15 century, for example). It could also have a major impact on the world's view of sex workers?

It all depends on what the texts say, how the people of the time interpret it, and how those interpretations fair the test of time. After all, there was a time when it was argued that Jesus was never 'of the flesh', but that wasn't an ideal worth dying for, so that got tossed out.

Comment: why is this closed?

Comment: Fayth85 Could you site the old and new texts' statements on these topics? I am not sure you have read through the original texts or maybe you are mixing this up with a different religion.    These seem like very broad generalizations that are different then what most people think the views on this religion are.  The phrase 'kill, convert, or subjugate' seems a bit under researched.

Comment: That is very religion based, but not exactly open to debate. It's all spelled out in the old testament exactly how to wage war, treat slaves, take wives, and who to accept in the religion. I can point you to Deuteronomy chapter 20, which spells out quite a bit of it. But the entire bible is rife with such orders.

Comment: @Fayth85  Originally, I did want to include the question as to why these texts were apocryphal, but I decided to get rid of that to narrow the scope.

Comment: @JohnWDailey If you were interested in why they were considered apocrypha, that would have made a good initial question before this one, and it still could make a good question, though that definitely would not be WorldBuilding. I have studied that a bit though, so I'll give you a teaser: sometimes a book cannot be authenticated (we are skeptical of who wrote it and when, despite the title/contents), sometimes the work looks like it got modified/tainted along the way (as appears to be the case with parts [not all] of book of Enoch), sometimes it is simple as because someone important said so.